# Winforms binding data

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, binding

If I have a grid with a list of items (`IList<x>`) and a textbox on the form, is there a way to bind the data so that as I click a row that the textbox.text gets updated, without doing it explicitly?

In other words, I want to be able to use Binding() or some other way, and not do

```
OnSelectionChanged
textbox.text = x.somefield
```

as I will have several controls that need updating, and I have to believe there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: BTW, your question doesn't seem to be specific to C#, so I took "C#" out of the title.

Answer (score 1):

If your grid is databound to your items

```
grid.DataSource=items;
```

You can use this:

```
textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", items, "somefield");
```